# WSO2 SAML SessionIndex missing

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml

I have WSO2 version 1.9.0 and have configured it for SSO, receiving a SAML2 token from third party identity server.  The SAML response I am receiving does not include sessionindex as part of the AuthnStatement.  WSO2 is throwing an exception since it is looking for the sessionindex attribute.  Is this required?  Is there a way to configure WSO2 so it doesn't need sessionindex? Is there configuring to tell the Identity Server to send sessionindex?

Comment: what is the third party idp you are using ?

Comment: SessionIndex is an optional attribute in the SAML2 schema, but it appears that it is required in WSO2.  It throws an exception if it does not exist. Is this a bug and WSO2 and should the logon continue without it?  We spoke with the third party idp and they are going to add in the SessionIndex as an attribute.